# How can I drop a hyperlink into a WPFcontrol?

Tags: wpf, url, hyperlink

I want to be able to drag a url from a web browser into my WPF app, and be able to get the URL for that site.

In Chrome, by dragging the page icon to the left of the URL will drag the URL to other documents and such, but I want to be able to get the URL in my WPF Drop event handler.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is make sure that `AllowDrop` property is set to true...

```
<TextBox Width="550" Height="25" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
  Margin="10" AllowDrop="True"/>
```

Take a look at this screenshot:

[image: AllowDrop]

As you can see I was able to drag the URL of this question from Chrome into my textbox just by setting `AllowDrop` property of the TextBox to `True`